# Show a 'Please wait' alert on JSP when button is clicked. when the processing is complete on servlet, remove the alert

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

My JSP page onDownload function calls a servlet with function as below.I would like to show an alert 'Please Wait' when the download button is clicked.. When the processing is complete on servlet, close the alert.

JSP Code:

```
    function onDownload(){
        var dType = 'download';
        var url = "<%=strDownloadURLTest%>"+"/downloadservlet?downloadType="+dType+"&PNumber="+'<%=custPNo%>';
        document.getElementById('downloadP').href = url;
        document.getElementById('downloadP').target='_blank';
    }
```

Processing at Servlet side, Code:

```
        byte content[]=null;
    try
    {   GetPDAO getPDAO= new GetPDAO();

          for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
          {
              content=getPDAO.getPFromEb( strPN);
               DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
               Date dateobj = new Date();
             content=null;
             if(content==null) 

              {  
                 Thread.sleep(5000);

             }
             else {
                 content=getPDAO.getPFromEb( strPN);
                 break;
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have agreed to use AJAX (after I do not find a other way round) to get a response from the servlet as below. However I'm using AJAX for the first time. I have added below code in my JSP and the servlet code remains same as before. Please suggest If it is done correctly?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '"<%=strDownloadURLTest%>"+"/downloaddocservlet?downloadType="+dType+"&PNumber="+"<%=custPNo%>"',
    data: {
        name: $('#dType').val()
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
    alert("Please wait.....");
        // this is where we append a loading image
    },
    success:function(responseText){
    alert.close();
        // successful request; do something with the data            
    },
    error:function(){
        // failed request; give feedback to user
    }
});
```